# Web scraping using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using the following code to submit a form using Python.
When the value entered is correct, it redirects to a new page called `http://localhost/a/my.php`. How do i check whether the page is redirected using python so that I can know that the values entered where correct.

```
from selenium import webdriver

webpage = r"http://localhost/a/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
for i in range(10):
    searchterm = i # edit me
    driver.get(webpage)
    sbox = driver.find_element_by_class_name("txtSearch")
    sbox.send_keys(searchterm)

    submit = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sbtSearch")
    submit.click()
```

Comment: You could use the `driver.current_url` to confirm it is the address you are looking for. If it does not work, maybe you have to wait for a page load, just add a `time.sleep(x)` or something.

Answer (score 1):

locate an element that **only exists** after the new DOM is loaded.  If you can find it, you are on the new page.

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("txtSearch")
    print("redirected to new page")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("oops, no redirect happened")
```

Comment: If navigation to new page failed `el = driver.find_element_by_class_name("txtSearch")` should give you `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Downvote?? May i know why?

Comment: I've already clarified. Your first approach is not efficient as script should break with exception if new page is not opened

Comment: just edited to catch `NoSuchElementException` instead of using `is_displayed()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using current_url:

```
driver.current_url
```

Answer (score 0):

to check whether the page is redirected properly or not, use a **`WebDriverWait`** (aka **"explicit wait"**) with proper
**`expected_conditions`** clause set to one of the following:

### Python :

1. **`url_to_be`** :

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_to_be("https://www.google.co.in/"))
   ```
2. **`url_matches`** :

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_matches("https://www.google.co.in/"))
   ```
3. **`url_contains`** :

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains("google"))
   ```
4. **`url_changes`** :

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_changes("https://www.google.co.in/"))
   ```